# CURL http authentication fails when setting CURL_OPTPOST to true

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to build a payment form that integrates with Firstdata's api. I need to post an XML string to their server. They also require a client side certificate and http authentication. My CURL set up  currently looks like this:

```
function firstdata_send($config_param, $data) {
  $config_default = array(
    'test' => FALSE,
  );
  // settings in $config_param will overwrite settings in $config_default
  $config = (object)array_merge($config_default, $config_param);

  if($config->test) {
    $url = 'https://ws.merchanttest.firstdataglobalgateway.com/fdggwsapi/services/order.wsdl';
  }
  else {
    $url = 'https://ws.firstdataglobalgateway.com/fdggwsapi/services/order.wsdl';
  }

  $ch = curl_init($url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "{$config->username}:{$config->password}");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, $config->pemfile);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLKEY, $config->keyfile);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLKEYPASSWD, $config->keypass);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);
  $result = curl_exec($ch);
  $result .= curl_error($ch);
  return $result;
}
```

Their server responds with `HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized`. But if I comment out the post options:

```
  //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
  //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
```

I get `HTTP/1.1 200 OK`. Unless I'm completely misunderstanding whats going on it seems like using post somehow interferes with the auth headers. I don't know what I'm missing.

Solved:

Turns out the ssl certificates the test account had generated were bad. I had to call their tech support and they had to regenerate the certs 3 times before the system would accept them. Sorry for wasting your time. I should have called them first. If anybody is interested the tech support number I called was (888) 477-3611. I think NomikOS was closest to being correct so I'll mark his as the answer and up vote the rest of you. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check you access credentials (username, password)

> 401 Unauthorized
>
> The request requires user authentication. The response MUST include a
>   WWW-Authenticate header field (section 14.47) containing a challenge
>   applicable to the requested resource. The client MAY repeat the
>   request with a suitable Authorization header field (section 14.8). **If
>   the request already included Authorization credentials, then the 401
>   response indicates that authorization has been refused for those
>   credentials**. If the 401 response contains the same challenge as the
>   prior response, and the user agent has already attempted
>   authentication at least once, then the user SHOULD be presented the
>   entity that was given in the response, since that entity might include
>   relevant diagnostic information. HTTP access authentication is
>   explained in "HTTP Authentication: Basic and Digest Access
>   Authentication" [43].

source: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.2

==

OBS: I recommend you this code to check for errors

```
// check for errors before close
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if ($result === false)
{
    echo curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: I don't understand how the same username and password can be accepted for GET and rejected for POST.

Comment: `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` only means that your request was successful, not that you are authenticated. Have you tried login with those credentials in another way? through a web page for example?

Answer (score 2):

Form what i see you need a `certificate` in `pem` format to use this service ....

A. Download the API https://www.firstdata.com/downloads/customerservice/30006_api_php.zip

B. You would see so many examples

Example Sales Info

```
    include"lphp.php";
    $mylphp=new lphp;

    $myorder["host"]       = "secure.linkpt.net";
    $myorder["port"]       = "1129";
    $myorder["keyfile"]    = "./YOURCERT.pem"; # Change this to the name and location of your certificate file 
    $myorder["configfile"] = "1234567";        # Change this to your store number 

    $myorder["ordertype"]    = "SALE";
    $myorder["result"]       = "LIVE"; # For a test, set result to GOOD, DECLINE, or DUPLICATE
    $myorder["cardnumber"]   = "4111-1111-1111-1111";
    $myorder["cardexpmonth"] = "01";
    $myorder["cardexpyear"]  = "05";
    $myorder["chargetotal"]  = "9.99";

    $myorder["addrnum"]   = "123";   # Required for AVS. If not provided, transactions will downgrade.
    $myorder["zip"]       = "12345"; # Required for AVS. If not provided, transactions will downgrade.
//  $myorder["debugging"] = "true";  # for development only - not intended for production use


  # Send transaction. Use one of two possible methods  #
//  $result = $mylphp->process($myorder);       # use shared library model
    $result = $mylphp->curl_process($myorder);  # use curl methods


    if ($result["r_approved"] != "APPROVED")    // transaction failed, print the reason
    {   
        print "Status: $result[r_approved]\n";
        print "Error: $result[r_error]\n";
    }
    else
    {   // success
        print "Status: $result[r_approved]\n";
        print "Code: $result[r_code]\n";
        print "OID: $result[r_ordernum]\n\n";
    }
```

Comment: I tried the PHP_FORM_MIN example but, I'm not getting any response from secure.linkpt.net.

Comment: Do you have proper certificate ?

Answer (score 1):

Just checked First Datas API is a SOAP based API...

The url to the wsdl only accepts GET because the wsdl is just the xml instruction set for sending soap calls.

[PHP soapclient class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php)